# Problema con reacts y setState (asincrono)

Tags: javascript, aplicación-web, reactjs

Tengo un problema con react js y con setState en la documentación dice que es asincrono.
Y el problema que tengo es que estoy usando un Select y según el valor que seleccione hace la petición con ajax a la base de datos pero como es asincrono el valor no se envia al hacer click en una opción la primera vez si no hasta el siguiente click en cualquier opción.

¿Cómo hago para mandar el valor actualizado?
He visto que setState puedo recibir un segundo argumento que es un callBack pero  no estoy seguro de como actualizar el valor.

```
       class HttpPeticion extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.state={lista:[],
              showData:false,showNodata:false,
              cantidadResultados:'',
              errorTipo:'',errorBool:false
            };
    }

 handlerData(data){

   if (typeof data=="undefined") return 0;

  let errorTipo=data.tipo;
  let errorBool=data.error;

  if(errorBool){
     this.setState({errorBool:data.error})
     this.setState({errorTipo:data.tipo})
  }
  else{
    let recordSize= data.records.length;
      if(recordSize<= 0) {
         this.setState({showData:false})//ocular resultados
         this.setState({showNodata:true})//muestra "no hay datos"
       }else{
        this.setState({showData:true});//mostrar resultados
        this.setState({showNodata:false})//ocultar "no hay datas"
        this.setState({lista:data.records});
      }
    this.setState({cantidadResultados:recordSize + ' Coincidencias' });
 }

 }


    componentWillReceiveProps(){
    axios.post(this.props.urlServer,{'tipo':this.props.tipo,'nombre':this.props.nombre})
      .then(res => {
         this.handlerData(res.data.data);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
         console.log(error);
      });
}


render(){
  return (
      <div>
         <div>{this.state.cantidadResultados}  </div>
         <div className={this.state.showData ? '': 'hidden' }>
            <ResultadoBusqueda datos={this.state.lista} />
          </div>

           <div className={this.state.showNodata ? '' : 'hidden'}>
             <h1>No hay ningun resultado </h1>
           </div>

           <div className={this.state.errorBool ? '':'hidden'}>
                <p>Un error ha ocurrido conectado con el ser servidor intente refresar la pagina(f5), si el problema
                     persiste contacte con el administrador.<a href="#">Mas informacion</a>  </p>
                <small>{this.state.errorTipo}</small>
           </div>
      </div>
  );
}
}

class ResultadoBusqueda extends React.Component{
    render(){
       return(
           <table>
              <thead>
                 <tr>
                  <th>Cuenta</th>
                  <th>Nombre</th>
                  <th>Precio</th>
                 </tr>
               </thead>
             <tbody>
            {
                 this.props.datos.map((item)=>{
                    return(
                       <tr key={item.cuenta.toString()}>
                       <td>{item.cuenta} </td>
                       <td>{item.nombre}</td>
                       </tr>
                    )
                 })
                }
            </tbody>
            </table>
      );
    }
```

}

```
class BusquedaAlumno extends React.Component {
setField (e) {
   //this.checkInput(e.target.value);
  this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})
}

render() {
   return (
      <div>

      <input type="text"
        onChange={(e)=>this.setField(e)}
        onKeyUp={(e)=>this.setField(e)}
        name="valor1"
       />
       <select onChange={(e)=>this.setField(e)} value={this.state.value} name="combo">
        <option value="-1">Selecciones</option>
         <option value="1">1</option>
         <option value="0">0</option>
       </select>

             <div>{this.state.valor1}</div>
              <div>{this.state.combo}</div>
         <HttpPeticion tipo={this.state.combo} nombre={this.state.valor1} urlServer={"http://localhost/viaLacteaQueryBusquedaId.php"} />
       </div>
    );
  }
```

Si me muestra los datos pero tiene ese pequeño inconveniente con el **select y el textbox**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que darte cuenta que si algo no cuadra en tu desarrollo, basicamente estas haciendo algo mal.
Además tienes un conjunto de malas practicas que estas llevando a cabo:

- HttpPeticion: un componente invisible? supongo que solo estas haciendo las peticiones al servidor con este componente, si es asi !Malo!. Deberias crear este componente como servicio que solo se encarge de peticiones y simplificar el uso de las url.
- No tiene sentido que primero establescas valores y luego hacer la solicitud, Primero has de hacer la solicitud y luego deacuerdo a la respuesta hacer establecer o no el valor escogido
- Utilizar string como propiedad y viceversa `e.target.name` y `name="valor1"`, establece un unico valor para lo que sera el atributo `name` ya sea en el estado o por variables
- Aislar acciones para que tu codigo sea escalable, separar eventos de `input` de los del `select` nunca sabras cuando tienes que aplicar mas logica a tus eventos

En conclución a tu pregunta y por las razones que te he dado yo escribiria tu componente de esta manera mas o menos dependiendo tus necesidades

```
import HttpPeticion from 'services/HttpPeticion';

class BusquedaAlumno extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({
      selectValue: '',
      inputValue: '',
    });
  }

  onInputChange() {
    this.setState({
      inputValue: e.target.value
    });
  }

  onSelectChange(e) {
    HttpPeticion.get('http://localhost/viaLacteaQueryBusquedaId.php', (data) => {
      this.setState({
        selectValue: e.target.value
        data: data
      });
    });
  }


  render() {
    const { inputValue, selectValue } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" onChange={this.onInputChange} value={inputValue} />

        <select onChange={this.onSelectChange} value={selectValue} >
          <option value="-1">Selecciones</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="0">0</option>
        </select>

        <div>{inputValue}</div>
        <div>{selectValue}</div>
       </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: ok lo tomare en cuenta pero usas alguna libreria para impletar el servicio ? a si no mas ,solo declaro un metodo en el componente que se llame GET en el sercvicio y lo llamo y listo?? no me funciona

Comment: @Ser Puedes usar fetch o superagent para hacer la llamada al endpoint y has la corrección que te sugiero en mi respuesta de mas abajo con Immutability Helpers, es esencial esa parte

Comment: @SergioRomero como comenta Carlos 'services/HttpPeticion' no es una libreria deberia ser una implementación propia tuya, mas o menos lo que estas haciendo en el componente HttpPeticion pero sin usarlo como reactjs component

Answer (score 1):

El método `setState` de la clase `Component` acepta un callback como segundo parámetro a ejecutarse **cuando ya se haya actualizado** el estado.

```
this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value }, () => {
  // estado actualizado, hacer algo
});
```

En el callback puedes poner cualquier lógica que dependa del éxito de la actualización de aquella entrada del estado.

Answer (score 1):

Ademas de las recomendaciones de @JoseAPL, Hay un problema en el handler que actualiza el estado, por cada input o select que actualiza el estado en realidad no estas actualizando el estado, lo estas remplazando por completo así que al hacer esto.

```
setField (e) {
    this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})
}
```

estas remplazando todo el estado y dejándolo únicamente con el campo que se actualice en ese instante, eliminando el anterior campo, la solución es utilizar  [Immutability Helpers](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html) de React.

Primero importa la libreria

```
import update from 'react-addons-update'
```

Luego define tu handler de esta manera.

```
setField (e) {
    this.setState(update(
        this.state,
        {[e.target.name]: {$set: e.target.value}}
    ))
}
```

Como buena practica siempre utiliza Immutability Helpers para mutar el state.